Try to get value from URL in NextJS
I trying to put value in url and trying to extract value in search.js with router, but I'm getting this error:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'q')

  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <input
      type="text"
      placeholder="Search..."
      value={searchValue}
      onChange={(e) => setSearchValue(e.target.value)}
      class="w-full px-4 py-2 rounded-md text-gray-900"
    />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>

const handleSubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default form submission
  router.push(`../search?q=${encodeURIComponent(searchValue)}`);
};

Search.js:
const Search = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    if (router.isReady) {
      setSearchQuery(router.query.q || '');
    }
  }, [router.isReady, router.query.q]);

  if (!router.isReady) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>; // Or some loading indicator
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Search Query: {searchQuery}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Search;


The useSearchParams hook in Next.js (introduced in Next.js 13 with the App Router) provides a more straightforward way to handle query parameters. This is especially useful when using the App Router with React Server Components.
Check this link:
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-search-params

It's a bit of a React anti-pattern to store passed data into local state, just reference the data directly, e.g.:
<p>Search Query: {router.query.q}</p>

If router.query is potentially undefined then use a guard clause or Optional Chaining operator
<p>Search Query: {router.query?.q ?? ""}</p>

<p>Search Query: {(router.query && router.query.q) ?? ""}</p>

If you must store it locally in state, like if you update it independently of the URL params, the solution is similar.
const router = useRouter();
const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState("");

useEffect(() => {
  if (router.isReady) {
    setSearchQuery(router.query?.q ?? "");
    // setSearchQuery((router.query && router.query.q) ?? "");
  }
}, [router.isReady, router.query]);

Also, ensure you are using the Pages router (imported from "next/router") and not the App router (imported from "next/navigation").
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

The Pages router should default router.query to an empty object {} and likely not require the checks mentioned above.

query: Object - The query string parsed to an object, including
dynamic route parameters. It will be an empty object during
prerendering if the page doesn't use Server-side Rendering. Defaults
to {}

An alternative may also be to use the useSearchParams hook.
'use client'

import { useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation';
...

const Search = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
 
  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState(
    () => searchParams.get('q') || ""
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (router.isReady) {
      setSearchQuery(searchParams.get('q') || '');
    }
  }, [router.isReady, searchParams]);

  if (!router.isReady) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>; // Or some loading indicator
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Search Query: {searchQuery}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Search;


Not getting error though, but not getting result as well, this is url http://localhost:3000/search?q=apple, should show Search Query: apple, but its just Search Query

If I try to use next/router it give Error: Error: NextRouter was not mounted. https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-router-not-mounted

it worked, thanks Drew
